# Powershell to rename files based on laast modified date

Tags: powershell

I would like to add an incremental number in front of my existing file names. However, I want to rename them based on their date modified information versus their name.

```
Sort-Object LastWriteTime | [ref]$i = 1; gci -file | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0:D} . {1}' -f $i.Value++, $_}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment outside of the delay-bind script block:

```
$inc = 1 # Increment
Get-ChildItem -File | Sort LastWriteTime | Foreach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { "{0} . {1}" -f $inc,$_ } -WhatIf
    $inc++
}
```

Remove `-WhatIf` if you are happy with the rename results.

Answer (score 0):

Or use script Scoping in the increment variable like this:

```
$inc = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' -File | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {'{0} . {1}' -f $script:inc++, $_.Name}
```